# Call remote servlet in the middle of a struts action

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts

Is it possible to call a remote servlet in the middle of a struts action and then use its result?

For instance, say i have two webapps A and B on the same server

Webapp A has an action which i would like to do something like:

```
processing
"call" servlet in webapp B
process using response from remote servlet
forward to whatever page is appropriate (success/error/etc)
```

In my specific example the servlet in webapp B will generate a PDF file which is returned in the response and i need use this pdf file in the further processing in the action in webapp A.

So i would like the call to the servlet to be like calling a method that returns what i need for further processing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or more powerful [Apache HttpClient Api](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e37)